# Given an object of @comments, with anywhere from 1-100s, how to grab the top 5, combine, and truncate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to generate a comment preview. I have @comments, which has 1 or comment comment items.

How can I take up to 5 comments. Combine them into a single string, spaced apart. And then take the first 100 characters? Where if there is less than 100 characters it won't break?

Thanks

Comment: Sample code and desired output, please.

Comment: Agree, it appears as though no effort was put into this. Did you try? Here's the [Ruby API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `truncate` Rails helper:

```
truncate(@comments.take(5).join(" "), :length => 100)
```

With truncate you can put a "..." at the end or make sure to not split a word (by using `:separator`)

(Note that it would be best to move some of the snippet-creation logic to the model)

Answer (score 0):

(Suppose that the content/body of the comment is accessible via :content)

```
@comments[0...5].map(&:content).join(' ').first(100)
```

It won't break if it's less than 100 characters.

But can't you only retrieve the first 5 comments from the db instead of retrieving all the comments and then keeping only 5 of those?

It would be much more efficient.

For instance:

```
@post.comments.select(:content).limit(5).map(&:content).join(' ').first(100)
```